# How to store an array in Cache in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cache, magento-2.1.3

I have loaded product attributes and manipulated its values as per my requirement. Now I want to save this array in Magento 2 Cache so that next time I don't have to create it again. What are the best practises to do the same.

Comment: Can you describe your actual requirement?

Comment: I want this so that next time I don't have to create the same array again as the manipulation takes a lot of time and this will also reduce the number of queries. Like if I have added some prefix in all product attributes in my model and now I want to save this in cache so that the same process must not happen again.

Comment: you can used session instade of cache.

Comment: @Dhiren: can you ellaborate

Answer (score 2):

Use some serialization api to convert your array to string.

```
$productIds = [ .. big array..];
$productIds = serialize($productIds);
$this->cache->save($productIds, $cacheKey))
```

Please pay attention that in 2.2 Magento introduce new interface `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface` special design for this

Comment: Yes, I am currently using the same technique. But want to make sure that it is a standard one as per magento 2 standards. Anyways thanx for the answer.

Comment: If it's an array you can just use `json_encode` and `json_decode`, then you don't have to deal with or worry about any unserialization attacks.